# Smooth Scroll to Custom View in Android

Tags: android, video

i am creating custom view extending surfaceview. View is Used to Display Video thumbs horizontally and is used as timeline of video. i want to add smooth scrolling to this custom view. i have tried fling animation class from androidx
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/fling-animation
but thisis used to scroll whole view. and using this fling view just graphically view is animating but its value remains the same. alternatively i have tried to use gesture listener but ufotunatilly. not worked can any one guide me in this matter.

**what actually i want smooth scrolling**
[image: What i want]

**what actually working**
[image: stuck when acion_up called]

```
public class TimelineView extends SurfaceView
```

touchmove Evvent method

```
  f2 = ((float) this.timeFullWidth) / ((float) this.viewWidth);
        j2 = this.startTouchTime - ((long) (f2 * (f - this.startTouch.x)));
        this.currentTime = j2;

        if (j2 < mediaList.get(0).getStartTrim()) {
            this.currentTime = glitchCamEditorMediaList.get(0).getStartTrim();
        }

        if (j2 > mediaList.get(0).getEndTrim()) {
            this.currentTime = glitchCamEditorMediaList.get(0).getEndTrim();
        }
```

============================================================================

```
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        int i = 0;
        for (Media media: this.mediaList) {
            long j = this.currentTime;
            int i2 = this.timeFullWidth;
            long j2 = j - ((long) (i2 / 2));
            if (media.getStartTimeLine() < j + ((long) (i2 / 2)) && media.getEndTrim() > j2) {
                drawCard(canvas, media);
            }
            i++;
        }
}
```